# Why Electron need to use the native modules? Electron embed a Node.js in it, whether this do not have the special `native modules`?

Tags: node.js, electron

When I read document [using-native-node-modules](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/using-native-node-modules):

> Native Node.js modules are supported by Electron, but since Electron has a different application binary interface (ABI) from a given Node.js binary (due to differences such as using Chromium's BoringSSL instead of OpenSSL), the native modules you use will need to be recompiled for Electron.

I have several questions about it:

1. how to understand `Electron has a different application binary interface (ABI) from a given Node.js binary`?
2. what's the function of `application binary interface (ABI)`  in there?
3. `the native modules you use will need to be recompiled for Electron.` , why Electron need to use the native modules? Electron embed a Node.js in it, whether this do not have the special `native modules`?

Comment: Computers execute long sequences of 1's and 0's. For example [my computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) executes 64 1's/0's at a time (an "instruction"), so here's a simple program that executes 5 instructions: `20 00 80 d2 40 05 80 d2 00 04 00 91 00 00 80 d2 30 00 80 d2 01 10 00 d4`. We can write a special program (a bunch of 1's and 0's) that executes strings of text and we can have special rules for how those strings should look, and call that "JavaScript", so this is a simple program: `console.log("hello world");`. So we have two types of code native code (the `20 00...`) or JS

Comment: In order to execute JavaScript code we need a special native program (a very long string of millions of these `20 00 80 d2...` etc.) in order to run a program like `console.log("hello world");`. V8/Node/Electron execute JavaScript, but running a program that parses JavaScript code is slow, so there is also a way to make them execute your own arbitrary native code. These are "native modules", they are long sequences of `20 00...` that you can pass to Electron in a special way to execute them.

Comment: Computers usually execute this long string of `20 00...` from left to right, but some instructions can tell it to "jump" to a different place in the string. So the instructions are numbered and one of the instructions can be "jump to instruction number 72". But programmers don't want to think about instruction numbers, so we give locations that can be jumped to names, so instruction #72 could be given a name like "printf". This is what the "application binary interface" is, but Node's and Electron's set of named instruction locations are different, so you need to compile 2 different binaries.